# Why aren't there more pauseless GC's

Tags: java, garbage-collection

All the GC's I know except Azul are somewhat concurrent, but have at least some small stop-the-world component. Why aren't there more GC's like Azul?

Did Azul patent their technology to the extent that it's not possible to do?

Or do the read/write barriers needed for pauseless operation incur so much overhead that they are impractical for most workloads?

Comment: I don't think this is a question about a concrete, answerable issue, and instead is one that invites personal opinion and conjecture.  So it would probably be better suited to a forum than Stack Overflow.

Comment: I just can guess but I assume that part of it is a license/patenting issue - azul wants to make some money anyways. Besides that, from their raw throughput experients in the whitepapers it seems as if there's no speed benefit for larger applications and on smaller ones the occasional hiccup due to stop-the-world collection most probably doesn't matter that much.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just asking why something hasn't been invented yet. No actual answer is possible.

Comment: Well, IMO there is a technical and objective answer: Is there anything that prevents people from implementing a pauseless GC?

Comment: @Pepijn, agreed, this is question is more about why people hate pauses but don't create pauseless JVMs except Azul's, so it does invite technical discussions.

Comment: Partly Azul's C4 puts a lot of work onto other CPU cores, hence it trades of the needs for additional cores to get very low (and dependable) latency from the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### ZGC

Starting from Java 11, there is a new [Z Garbage Collector](https://openjdk.org/jeps/333) (ZGC) available for Linux/x64 JDK (Windows/macOS since Java 14):

> The Z Garbage Collector, also known as ZGC, is a scalable low latency garbage collector designed to meet the following goals:
>
> - Pause times do not exceed 10ms
> - Pause times do not increase with the heap or live-set size
> - Handle heaps ranging from a few hundred megabytes to multi terabytes in size

You can enable ZGC by specifying the following JVM arguments:

```
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseZGC
```

(For Java 15+, `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions` is [unnecessary](https://openjdk.org/jeps/377))

---

### Shenandoah GC

Also, since Java 12, there is [Shenandoah GC](https://openjdk.org/jeps/189) available for all platforms. ShenandoahGC has similar characteristics as ZGC but its implementation is different.

```
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseShenandoahGC
```

(For Java 15+, `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions` is [unnecessary](https://openjdk.org/jeps/379))

Shenandoah GC was also [backported](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/shenandoah/Main) to Java 11 (11.0.9) and Java 8 (only RedHat builds of JDK 8 include Shenandoah).

Comment: _Shenandoah_ is _not_ pauseless though, it has 4 STW events: `Initial Mark/Final Mark/Init Update References/Final Update References`, but they are rather small.

Comment: "Pause times do not exceed 10ms" - in other words: It has pauses ...

Comment: @BodoThiesen In Java 16, they reduced pauses to 1ms ([blog post](https://malloc.se/blog/zgc-jdk16)).

Answer (score 10):

Based on [the Azul whitepaper on C4](http://www.azulsystems.com/sites/default/files/images/c4_paper_acm.pdf), it looks like C4 is a very new technology, an implementation of an algorithm published in 2005, first on custom hardware and then ported specifically to Linux on x86, and the JVM implementation sits very close to the kernel VM system.

Since OpenJDK/HotSpot is widely used on a number of platforms and in major production workloads, it tends to move more slowly when adopting major innovations in algorithms (the switch to TimSort is a good example). The Java 8 versions introduced the first major overhaul of the GC system in years (with the elimination of the PermGen), and improvements such as C4, if practical to be ported cross-platform or abstracted without significant downside to JVM bookkeeping internals, are likely to be tried out and then adopted into OpenJDK/HotSpot in upcoming versions.

Comment: Good point, in fact, early Azul used hardware tag bits and then Linux kernel level modifications and it's still Linux-only solution, vs. Shenandoah "BTW, to set the record straight: C4 (in the form that has been shipping commercially inside our Zing JVM for a while now) is pure software, and it runs on vanilla, untouched Linux/x86 distros (RHEL 5.x/6.x, CentOS 5.x/6.x, SLES, Ubuntu, …) and the unmodified kernels that come with them." https://rkennke.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/shenandoah-a-pauseless-gc-for-openjdk/

Answer (score 8):

Implementing garbage collectors is quite tricky and there are not many applications that truly justify a pauseless collector. As you mentioned, read/write barriers to impose a pretty high overhead that you only want to pay if you absolutely need low latency and are willing to take a hit on throughput.

That said, a low-pause GC called Shenandoah is being implemented in this JEP: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/189 . As a Java programmer, I'm hopeful that it will be available in a few years.

Answer (score 1):

Zing's patented C4 garbage collector was first described [in 2005](https://www.azul.com/resources/azul-technology/azul-c4-garbage-collector/), and OpenJDK waited until 2018 to add [the pauseless ZGC garbage collector](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/333). Patents in the US last 20 years from first filing, and Sun/Oracle spent a huge amount of effort on various garbage collectors in the meantime. It's pretty clear that this was a patent issue.

Based on having used both Zing and G1 early on, and having read about the tradeoffs of Shenandoah and others, I suspect that ZGC will become the default once Oracle feels it is sufficiently mature.